# Caught in an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, infinite-loop

I'm trying to perform a check on some information in a database. If i run the following code without it being in a loop it runs fine, but only checking the first row, what i need it to do is to check the names and dates for each row.

If i understand the while loop correctly it would move my cursor to the next row then just run the code again. Can anyone see why this is looping until my program crashes?

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
String titlefromdb = cursor.getString(3);



if (strTitle.equals(titlefromdb)&& cursor.getString(1).equals(dateselforap)) {


Log.d("insidematch", "date and title matched");

final Dialog matchdiag = new DialogCW2Organisor.this);

matchdiag.setContentView(R.layout.apptmatch);
matchdiag.setTitle("View/Edit Appointment");
matchdiag.setCancelable(true);

TextView matchtxt = (TextView) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.matchtxt);

matchtxt.setText("Appointment \""+ titlefromdb + "\" already exists, please choose a different event title");

Button btnmatchok = (Button) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.btnmatch);
btnmatchok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

//on click for cancel button
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
matchdiag.dismiss();}
        });
matchdiag.show();
} else {
addAppt(strTime, strTitle, strDet);
cursor = getAppts();
dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code? its really hard to read without indentation

Answer (score 1):

Try moving to the first record before calling moveToNext().
Move your functionality into a do/while loop so you can still grab the first record

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
    return; //nothing to do since the cursor is empty

do
{
    String titlefromdb = cursor.getString(3);

    if (strTitle.equals(titlefromdb)&& cursor.getString(1).equals(dateselforap)) {
        Log.d("insidematch", "date and title matched");

        final Dialog matchdiag = new DialogCW2Organisor.this);

        matchdiag.setContentView(R.layout.apptmatch);
        matchdiag.setTitle("View/Edit Appointment");
        matchdiag.setCancelable(true);

        TextView matchtxt = (TextView) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.matchtxt);

        matchtxt.setText("Appointment \""+ titlefromdb + "\" already exists, please choose a different event title");

        Button btnmatchok = (Button) matchdiag.findViewById(R.id.btnmatch);
        btnmatchok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        //on click for cancel button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matchdiag.dismiss();
            }
        });

        matchdiag.show();

    } else {
        addAppt(strTime, strTitle, strDet);
        cursor = getAppts();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: You can always try surrounding the code with a try-catch block and see what gets caught.

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into the infinite loop problem, which really baffled me as well, since a while !moveToNext() loop should *definitely* finish.

However, the workaround is to use a for loop over the length of the cursor, and process each cursor.moveToPosition(i).

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cursorLen; i++) {
  if (!cursor.moveToPosition(i)) {
    return;
  }
  // process your cursor
}
```

I feel like this must be a bug with the Cursor implementation, because a while loop over cursor.moveToNext() should always finish.